# Test email sent but not delivered by WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, email-validation, dokan

The test email has been sent by WordPress. but not delivered to sender .. i used a dokan plugin in my project and at signup i used a email  verification when i signup email send but not delivered at destination

**here is some error notification by wordpress**

```
The test email has been sent by WordPress. Please note this does NOT mean it has been delivered. See wp_mail in the Codex for more information. The headers sent were:

MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
From: quamarabbas3@gmail.com\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n

Current mail settings

SendMail path (UNIX): /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

SMTP server (Windows): localhost

SMTP port (Windows): 25

Add X header: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Please tell us, what Dokan plugin are you using? Also, what exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish by using this plugin?

I will edit this post to provide further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for response i used dokan plugin for multi vendor when a new vendor register a verification email send to vendor email but a problem is email is send but not delivered ..